# Configure NGINX redirect rules and proxy rules

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to create an nginx configuration file with redirect rules and proxy rules. Below are the requirements and examples. Can somebody give some help?

The required redirect rules are: If there is no "/outer" after the domain name, add it and redirect web url with 301. I want the "/outer" presents in the browser. Below are some examples. If I input the left path in browser, I want nginx redirect the path to the right one.

```
https://design.mydomain.com -> https://design.mydomain.com/outer/
https://design.mydomain.com/ -> https://design.mydomain.com/outer/
https://design.mydomain.com/my/home.html?t=now -> 
https://design.mydomain.com/outer/my/home.html?t=now
```

The required proxy rules are: If the url includes leading "/outer", remove "/outer" from the path and  proxy the request to the backend web server. For the example below, If I input the left path in browser, nginx should call the backend web server with the right path.

```
https://design.mydomain.com/outer/my/home.html?t=now  -->  https://webserver/my/home.html?t=now
```

The web server folder structure is as below. It is already running in the backend with internal host name webserver.

```
|--index.html
|--my
     |--home.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to forward a request to /path via proxy_pass for all requests to /outer/path, you can add the following block. Although the if statement may seem superfluous, it's the easiest way to store the request path after /outer in $1 (inspired by this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/699695/nginx-proxy-pass-remove-url-substring)

```
location /outer {
    if ($request_uri ~* "/outer(.*)") {
        proxy_pass https://webserver$1;
    } 
}
```

In order to redirect all non-/outer requests to insert /outer right after the domain name, you can create a location block that matches all urls, since the location block above will take precedence for matches to /outer (and therefore /outer won't be added in front of request_uris already containing /outer).

```
location / {
    return 301 $https://design.mydomain.com/outer$request_uri;
}
```